# How do you justify neglecting electron-electron interaction in the Drude model?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, classical-mechanics

I'm sure there's some way to justify it. Maybe a screening effect?

Answer (score 2):

Screening sounds like it should help, but remember that screening, too, is a form of electron-electron interaction. I think ultimately it comes down to the remarkable results of Fermi liquid theory, which is that even once you take into account e-e interactions you still have electron-like quasiparticles moving in an electron-like way, and scattering off impurities in a Drude-like way. So in the end it is another one of the "accidentally correct" aspects of the Drude model (the other being its neglect of Pauli exclusion) that coincidentally leads to a working Drude formula.